# Reusing uitextfield for input validation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, authentication, uitextfield

I am creating a login flow and I am re-using my textfields.  I want to know what I am doing wrong on this or how can I can change the validation on textfield. I created a counter to see if that helps with determining the the options to use on that count. When I get to email validation it's not working correctly.  No matter what I input I get alert.

```
final class SignupViewController: UIViewController, ViewPassesData, UITextFieldDelegate  {

@IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundViewImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var firstLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var secondLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var secondLine: UIView!

enum SignUpStage {
    case name
    case email
    case password
    case phone
    case text
    case notifications
    case location
}

var stage: SignUpStage?
var dictionary: [String: String] = [:]




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setLayoutForStage()
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    firstNameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    lastNameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
func isValidEmail(email:String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    let result = emailTest.evaluate(with: email)
    return result

}
func isPasswordValid(text: String) -> Bool {
    let passWordRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z]{0,9}"
    let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", passWordRegEx)
    let result = passwordTest.evaluate(with: text)
    return result
}

@IBAction func validationTextField(_ sender: UITextField) {


}
```

This is where I am having trouble with my code. - Update I have fixed the issue with help from @Julio Cesar Arregoitía Val comment.

```
   @IBAction func actionButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Signup") as? SignupViewController, let stage = nextStage() else { return }
    vc.stage = stage
    setDictionaryValues()

    switch currentStage {
    case .name:
        if firstNameTextField.text == "" || lastNameTextField.text == "" {
           alertMessage()
        }
        else {
            vc.dictionary = dictionary
           self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    case .email:
        currentStage = .email
        if isValidEmail(email: "\(firstNameTextField.text!)") == true {
            vc.stage = stage
            vc.dictionary = dictionary
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
        else {
            alertMessage()
        }
    case .password:
        currentStage = .password
        if firstNameTextField.text != "" && isPasswordValid(text: "\(firstNameTextField.text!)") == true {
            vc.stage = stage
            vc.dictionary = dictionary
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
        else {
            alertMessage()
        }
    case .phone:
        currentStage = .phone
    case .text:
        currentStage = .text
    case .notifications:
        currentStage = .notifications
    case .location:
       currentStage = .location
    }
}


@IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

private func setLayoutForStage() {
    guard let stage = stage else { return }
    switch stage {
    case .name:
        firstLabel.text = "first name".uppercased()
        secondLabel.text = "last name".uppercased()
    case .email:
        firstLabel.text = "email".uppercased()
        secondLabel.isHidden = true
        lastNameTextField.isHidden = true
        secondLine.isHidden = true
    case .password:
         button.setNeedsDisplay()
        firstLabel.text = "password".uppercased()
        firstNameTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        secondLabel.isHidden = true
        lastNameTextField.isHidden = true
        secondLine.isHidden = true
    case .phone:
        firstLabel.text = "phone number".uppercased()
        firstNameTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        secondLabel.isHidden = true
        lastNameTextField.isHidden = true
        secondLine.isHidden = true
    case .text: break
    case .notifications: break
    case .location: break
    }
}
func resetTextFields() {

}

func setDictionaryValues() {
    guard let stage = stage else { return }
    switch stage {
    case .name:
        dictionary["first_name"] = firstNameTextField.text?.capitalizingFirstLetter()
        dictionary["last_name"] = lastNameTextField.text?.capitalizingFirstLetter()
    case .email:
        dictionary["email"] = firstNameTextField.text
        firstNameTextField.text = ""
    case .password:
        dictionary["password"] = firstNameTextField.text
        dictionary["password_confirmation"] = firstNameTextField.text
    case .phone:
        dictionary["phone_number"] = firstNameTextField.text
        dictionary["contact_preference"] = "EMAIL"
    case .text: break
    case .notifications: break
    case .location: break
    }
}

// TODO: make this all one system
private func nextStage() -> SignUpStage? {
    guard let stage = stage else { return .name }
    switch stage {
    case .name: return .email
    case .email: return .password
    case .password: return .phone
    case .phone:
        guard let nextVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "text") as? TextPhoneViewController, firstNameTextField.text?.count == 10 else {
            return nil
        }
        nextVC.dictionary = dictionary
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
        return nil
    case .text: return nil
    case .notifications: return nil
    case .location: return nil
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- I think your main prob
lem is that in case 0 the `i +=1` it is placed only in the else, and when it is evaluated your vc is pushed by the

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

2- I think that you want the `i` for get to know in what stage you are. Use an Enum var for that:

```
var currentStage: SignUpStage = .name
@IBAction func actionButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

switch currentStage {
case .name:
    // Check name
    // ...
    // if it is ok
    fallthrough

case .email:
    currentStage = .email
    // Check .email:
    // ...
    // if it is ok
    fallthrough

case .password:
    currentStage = .password

    // All the others checks like this
}
```

The `fallthrough` let you evaluate the next condition only if you want,

3- You don't need to put:

```
lert.dismiss(animated: true, completion nil)
```

Just do this

```
lert.addAction( UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil) )
```

and you will get the same result.

Regards

Comment: Thanks with your help I was able to figure it out.

Comment: It is a placer to me.